# Ionic2 "ionViewDidEnter" method is very slow first time

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

Can you tell me why below functionality has huge delay on first-time load? On 2nd time where it is normal.The same delay is on the actual device too.Please see the attached video.

**Note :**
The issue here is firebase bind `this.eventData.getEventList().on('value', snapshot => {}` When I remove it all are working fine.Do you know how to do it differently?

**Video:** [**Video about this issue**](https://youtu.be/dPWEAY5dqyA)

**.html**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let event of eventList" (click)="goToEventDetail(event.id)" color="secondary">
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>Event Name: <strong>{{event?.name}}</strong></p>
      <p>Ticket: <strong>${{event?.price}}</strong></p>
      <p>Cost: <strong>${{event?.cost}}</strong></p>
      <p>Date: <strong>{{event?.date}}</strong></p>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventDetailPage } from '../event-detail/event-detail';
import { EventData } from '../../providers/event-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-event-list',
  templateUrl: 'event-list.html',
})

export class EventListPage {
  public eventList: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public eventData: EventData) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.eventData.getEventList().on('value', snapshot => {
      let rawList = [];
      snapshot.forEach(snap => {
        rawList.push({
          id: snap.key,
          name: snap.val().name,
          price: snap.val().price,
          cost: snap.val().cost,
          date: snap.val().date
        });
      });
      this.eventList = rawList;
    });
  }
}
```

**provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class EventData {

  public currentUser: any;
  public eventList: any;

  constructor() {
    this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.eventList = firebase.database().ref('userProfile/' + this.currentUser + '/eventList');

  }

  getEventList(): any {
    return this.eventList;
  }

}
```

Comment: check in postman you can see the time duration that have been taken for the api call if that is same as this then back end should send the response fast

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the changes are not being detected. Try wrapping your `push` into `NgZone::run()`.

First, import NgZone:

`import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';`

Then, inject on your constructor:

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone /* ... other injections ... */) {
    // constructor code ...
}
```

Then use the run function to push the data into the array:

```
snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        rawList.push({
            id: snap.key,
            name: snap.val().name,
            price: snap.val().price,
            cost: snap.val().cost,
           date: snap.val().date
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if this is gonna work for you, but it's worth a try.

Comment: sorry.no difference.same delay there too. is that an issue of this firebase bind `this.eventData.getEventList().on('value', snapshot => {` ?

Comment: I dont think so... this looks okay.. can you put a console log inside the callback to see if its being called right away or if it is only being called when the view is updated?